# display random image url from folder

Tags: php

I have a php code which uses every image in a folder and echos the url on my page.

what i need help with is making the php code randomize the list of urls each time the page is loaded.

The code that i have is:

```
<?php 
 if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
      {
            $thelist .= '<div data-delay="5"><img src="images/'.$file.'"></div>';
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
?>
<?=$thelist?>
```

many thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem and what do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to put all filenames into an array and then use `shuffle()` to mix it up. Then you can iterate over the array and output the images. It should look something like this:

```
<?php 
 $thelist = "";
 if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
   $images = array();
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            array_push($images, 'images/'.$file);
      }
   }
   closedir($handle);
   shuffle($images);
   foreach ($images as $image) {
      $thelist .= '<div data-delay="5"><img src="'.$image.'"></div>';
   }
   echo $thelist;
 }
?>
```

By using `glob()` instead of `opendir()` you could shorten the code significantly, as `glob()` returns an array and then you only would need to shuffle that one.

Answer (score 0):

put your file links into an array and shuffle it with the function [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.shuffle.php)

```
<?php 

if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileTab[] = $file; 
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);
    foreach($fileTab as $file) {
        $thelist .= '<div data-delay="5"><img src="images/'.$file.'"></div>';
    }
}
?>
<?=$thelist?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly creating divs in the while loop, use it only to store all urls in an Array. Then [shuffel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) that array, and use a foreach loop in order to populate $thelist.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `glob()`?

```
$images = glob('images/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

shuffle($images);

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<div data-delay="5">
              <img src="', $image ,'">
          </div>';
}
```